# Dúvida em herança c#

Tags: c#, herança

Tenho uma dúvida conceitual sobre herança, onde tenho um aluno e em algum momento esse aluno irá virar um empregado e esse empregado ele nasceu no sistema como aluno e se for tudo ok durante o processo virará empregado, então tenho:

```
public class Aluno { public int Id {get;set;} public string Nome { get; set;} }

public class Empregado : Aluno { public decimal Salario { get; set;} }
```

Então um aluno é criado:

```
var aluno = new Aluno { Id = 1, Name = "Roberto" };
```

A minha dúvida é como fazer esse aluno dias depois virar um empregado, mantendo o mesmo Id e Nome?

Comment: Você está tentando modelar suas classes baseado num *workflow* (aluno > Empregado), e talvez não seja a melhor forma (isso, minha humilde opinião). Vamos pensar assim: todo empregado, necessariamente um dia já foi aluno? Acredito que a resposta seja **não**, por isso essa modelagem não me parece a ideal. Talvez você possa modelar uma classe chamada "Pessoa", e Aluno e Empregado herdam dela, estendendo assim "Pessoa", me parece fazer mais sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez haja um problema com a sua maneira de pensar. Do jeito que o seu código está estruturado, um Empregado também é um Aluno. O conceito de herança não significa ir de um estágio a outro, mas sim especialização.

**Edit:** Não notei algumas informações a respeito do empregado, então estou mudando a resposta.

Visto que você quer manter as informações de nome e ID, talvez seja uma boa ideia abstrair a lógica de "evolução" para uma classe abstrata separada, que te dará a oportunidade de acrescentar informações específicas de cada "cargo", por exemplo:

Uma classe pessoa como base, para manter os seus dados cadastrais:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}

    public virtual Cargo Cargo {get;set;}
}
```

*Cargo* é uma classe abstrata, e você terá duas classes definindo comportamentos diferentes que herdarão dela.

```
public abstract class Cargo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class CargoEstudante : Cargo
{
    public bool Concluido {get;set;}
}

public class CargoEmpregado : Cargo
{
    public decimal Salario {get;set;}
}
```

Sendo assim, você poderia especificar métodos de extensão para facilitar a sua vida e descobrir se uma Pessoa é estudante ou trabalha (ou os dois caso faça sentido em sua aplicação).

```
public static class ExtensoesPessoa
{
    public static bool IsEstudante(this Pessoa p)
    {
        return p.Cargo is CargoEstudante;
    }

    public static bool IsEmpregado(this Pessoa p)
    {
        return p.Cargo is CargoEmpregado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom dia danspark, sua solução não engloba as características específicas de um empregado (salário).

Comment: @GustavoSantos Bom dia, editei a resposta de acordo com o que falou, acho que agora está resolvendo o problema corretamente.